# Acentuación de plurales en monosílabos con tilde diacrítica

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, diacríticos

Recientemente me ha entrado la duda de si el plural de *té* llevaba tilde diacrítica o no, puesto que *tés* no corre el riesgo de confundirse con **tes* dado que esta última no existe.

Leo [en el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=t%C3%A9):

> **té.** ‘Árbol cuyas hojas se emplean para infusiones y, especialmente, la propia infusión’: *«Vos no sabés ni hacer un té de saquitos»* (Cuzzani *Zorro* [Arg. 1988]). Se escribe con tilde diacrítica, en oposición al pronombre de segunda persona del singular *te* y al nombre de la letra *t*, que se escriben sin tilde. Su plural, *tés*, se escribe también con tilde: *«Me cargan los tés sin gusto a té»* (Donoso *Elefantes* [Chile 1995]). No es aceptable la grafía galicada *thé*.

Así que confirmado, se escribe *tés*, pero ¿por qué? ¿Cuál es la regla que aplica al formar en general los plurales de voces con tildes diacríticas? ¿Se mantiene siempre aunque no exista riesgo de confusión con otras voces? ¿O es este un caso particular y en realidad no hay otras voces a las que les suceda esto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si buscas la definición de [te](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZHbpNE9%7CZHbtI24), la primera acepción es

> *Te*
>
> 1. f. Letra t y sonido que representa.

Entonces, es posible decir, por ejemplo:

> Los estudiantes hispanohablantes del idioma alemán siempre tienen problemas con las tes.

Esto quiere decir que el idioma alemán usa muchas letras "t" (tes), sobre todo al final de las palabras, que los estudiantes hispanohablantes generalmente olvidan pronunciar. *Olvidan pronunciar las tes.*

Ergo es necesaria la tilde diacrítica en el plural de `té` por el mismo motivo que en su versión singular.

Comment: Vale, acabo de ganarme un _facepalm_. :-D